# Python: subprocess.call broken pipe

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to call a shell script in python, but it keeps reporting broken pipe error (the result is OK, but i don't want to see the error message in STDERR). I have pinpointed the cause, and it can be reproduced as the following snippet:

`subprocess.call('cat /dev/zero | head -c 10 | base64', shell=True)`

AAAAAAAAAAAAAA==

cat: write error: Broken pipe

`/dev/zero` is an infinite stream, but the `head -c 10` only reads 10 bytes from it and exits, then cat will get SIGPIPE because of the peer has closed the pipe. There's no broken pipe error message when i run the command in shell, but why python shows it?

Comment: The error goes away when you skip the [uuoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat): `subprocess.call('head -c 10 < /dev/zero | base64', shell=True)`

Comment: @larsmans: you could put that as an answer

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: actually, I strongly prefer your answer.

Comment: @larsmans: it depends on what he's doing. If it's not just simple things like `head` and `base64`, it may be too difficult to manage in pure Python. Yours solves the question *as asked*, which is of value.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: true. Still, I would only post an answer if I *understood* what was happening, and I don't. I've never seen `cat` complain about a broken pipe before, and have always relied on it exiting silently when the pipe is closed.

Answer (score 9):

The default action to SIGPIPE signal is to terminate the program. Python interpreter changes it to SIG_IGN to be able to report broken pipe errors to a program in the form of exceptions.

When you execute `cat ... |head ...` in shell, `cat` has default SIGPIPE handler, and OS kernel just terminates it on SIGPIPE.

When you execute `cat` using `subprocess` it derives SIGPIPE handler from its parent (python interpreter), SIGPIPE is just ignored and `cat` handles the error itself by checking `errno` variable and printing error message.

To avoid error messages from `cat` you can use `preexec_fn` argument to subprocess.call:

```
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
subprocess.call(
    'cat /dev/zero | head -c 10 | base64',
    shell = True,
    preexec_fn = lambda: signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)
)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much for that, just solved my problem with a shell script using cat (and I'm fairly sure it's not a uuoc, maybe that's another question!).

Comment: Excellent! Fixed a tr: broken pipe error caused by calling a bash script with subprocess.call()

Answer (score 2):

In this trivial case at least you're not gaining anything by using shell commands—and you're losing portability and speed.

Python 2 code:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(open('/dev/zero', 'rb').read(10))
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA=='
>>> base64.b64encode('\0' * 10)
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA=='
```

In Python 3 (code will also run in 2.6+, though it will return `str` rather than `bytes` instances):

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(open('/dev/zero', 'rb').read(10))
b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA=='
>>> base64.b64encode(b'\0' * 10)
b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA=='
```

In each case, the first example retains the usage of `/dev/zero` (in itself non-portable, but never mind), the second produces the effect, though I imagine it's not what you want specifically?

Comment: +1. `'\x00'` can also be written `'\0'` (or `b'\0'` in Python 3.x).

Comment: I think I prefer subdir's answer, which addresses the question directly, and explains the problem.